# Fastest way to find an item in a collection

Tags: python

Right now my I have a script which parses all of the items, places it into a collection (currently a list which is slow), and then I want to return the element that matches a list of keywords that I've inputted beforehand.

What would be the best type of collection for this purpose and is there any way i can find my desired element without having to loop through the whole collection?

Thank you.

Edit:

An example [sitemap](http://deadstock.ca/sitemap_products_1.xml)

```
def parse(sitemap):
    req = urllib.request.urlopen(sitemap)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req, 'xml')
    soup.prettify()
    inventory_url = []


    for item in soup.find_all('url'):


        inventory_url.append(item.find('loc').text)


        #matches all keywords
        #keywords is a list of string
    for item in inventory_url:
        if all(kw in item for kw in keywords):
            return item
```

Comment: show us some code.

Comment: Either a `set` or a `dictionary` is the likely answer, although it is hard to say anything definite without context, something which is noticeably lacking from your question.

Comment: What do you mean when you say *and then I want to return the element that matches a list of keywords that I've inputted beforehand.* ? You want it to match things like a search engine? Are the keywords regular expressions? Something else? What's your expected input and output?

Comment: Sorry for being too vague.. editing in some code right now

Comment: what do you mean by "the element that matches a list of keywords"?

Comment: return the element in the list whose string contains the strings in the keywords